# cannot start eclipse neon on macOS Sierra

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I run a new Mac with OS Sierra Version 10.12.1, installed Java 8.111 which is recognised successfully by the test program and eventually installed eclipse neon 4.2. But when I try to start it, I get the message "To open “Eclipse” you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime". There is a link to the site "https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US" dated from July 22 2015 and telling to install java for OSX 2015-01 for the OS 10.7 to 10.11. There is also a link with explanation starting with a warning, that this information is about an older unsupported Java version, Download the latest version of Java for OS X directly from Oracle. There is some information hard to understand ( why should Java 6 be installed, since it is deprecated and even dangerous?)
Since I didn't find any other mean and thought the page was maybe not updated I installed the tool, but the launch eclipse still stops unexpectedly with an error report.
Thanks for ideas to overcome this

Comment: You need the Java 8 JDK (the JRE will not do) from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html Eclipse Neon requires Java 8 so the old Java 6 is no good.

Comment: Download the 64-bit version.

Comment: @greg-449 why will the JRE not do?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen For some reason on macOS the Oracle JRE only installs the browser plugin code and not the 'java' command. Using the wrong one is a common problem with macOS users.

Answer (score 0):

Like @greg-449 pointed out, install Java 8 JDK (not JRE) to get Eclipse Neon running on macOS Sierra.

Do not install Java 6. I tried that, and got an error message saying Java 8 is needed.